# If a sequence of summable sequences converges to a sequence, then that sequence is summable.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, normed-spaces

Let $(a_i)^n$ be a sequence of complex sequences each of which are summable (they converge).  Then if they have a limit, the limit sequence $(b_i)$ is also summable.  All under the sup norm for sequences.

Let $(a_i)^n$ sum to $c_n$.  I.e. for all $\epsilon \gt 0$, there's $N$ such that $m \gt N \implies |\sum_{i=1}^m a_i^n - c_n| \lt \epsilon$.  I want to show that there's $b$ such that $|\sum_{i=1}^m b_i - b| \lt \epsilon$ similarly.  Let $b = \lim c_n$.   Where to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(**edited**) This doesn't work, the example is pointwise convergent:  Consider the alternating sequence $x=(-1,1,-1,1,\ldots)$ and let $x_n$ take the first $n$ terms of $x$ and be zero afterwards. $x_n$ converges pointwise to $x$, and is summable, but the (pointwise) limit $x$ is not summable.

---

Here is a uniform convergence counterexample: Take the sequence $x(i) = 1/i$, which is not summable. Now take $x_n$ to match $x$ for the first $n$ terms and be zero after. $x_n$ converges to $x$ uniformly, but the limit is not summable.

Comment: Bah humbug.  This sucks then.  :(

Comment: Does it converge pointwise to $x$ under the sup norm?

Comment: $\sup_{i\geq 1}|x_n^i - x^i| = 1$, so your counterexample doesn't work here!

Comment: *Celebrates*  HOORAY!!!!  It still might work

Comment: @EnjoysMath Sorry... I think it still broke :(  perhaps need some uniform control over the summability of individual sequences.

Comment: @EnjoysMath  Well, for absolute convergence there is always the dominated convergence theorem , which doesn't even need uniform limits (if the sequences are bounded in absolute value by a single summable sequence, then the limit of the sums converges to the sum of the limit).  Other than that, seems rather tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_i)^n$ be a sequence of summable sequences that converges to $(b_i)$, and let each be summable to $c_n$ respectively. I want to show that the sequence $c_n$ is Cauchy and thus has a limit $c \in \mathbb{C}$.  $|c_n - c_m| \approx \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}|\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i^n - \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i^m|$.  Still working...